# Showing weakly continuous operators are continuous without using weak topology

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, and let $T:X\rightarrow Y$ be a linear map such that $f\circ T$ is continuous for all $f\in Y'$.  Show that $T$ is continuous.

Now I think this problem is trivial once you have the notion of weak topology.  But without that notion, I'm not sure how to approach this.  I tried using the inequalities $|(f\circ T)(x)|\leq(||f\circ T||)(||x||)$ and  $|(f\circ T)(x)|\leq(||f|||)(||Tx||)$, but I don't see how that gets us any closer to find what $||Tx||$ is less than or equal to.  Maybe a judicious choice of $f$ would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this using the closed graph theorem. So take some sequence $(x_n,Tx_n)$ for $(x_n)\subseteq X$ such that $(x_n)$ converges to some $x\in X$ and $(Tx_n)$ converges to some $y\in Y$. Now you need to show $Tx=y$. So, assume that this is false and try to get to a contradiction to the continuity assumption for some 'good' $f\in Y'$.