# Weakly continuous operators are continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm trying to understand [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3114233/showing-weakly-continuous-operators-are-continuous-without-using-weak-topology) on MSE.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, and let $T:X\rightarrow Y$ be a linear map such that $f\circ T$ is continuous for all $f\in Y'$.  Show that $T$ is continuous.

Jonas provides a good simple start of the problem but I was not able to physically show the contradiction. I have found a similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337103/a-linear-operator-between-banach-spaces-is-weakly-continuous-iff-norm-continuous) which they took a completely different route and user38355 didn't clearly give proof of the direction I'm trying to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I am going to follow Jonas' approach with some more details.

Both the spaces are Banach, so we can apply the closed graph theorem. This means, we take a sequence $(x_n)\subset X$ such that $x_n\to0$ and we **assume** that $T(x_n)\to y$ where $y\in Y$ is some element. If we manage to show that $y=0$, then by the closed graph theorem we can conclude that $T$ is bounded (this is the standard application).

Assume that $y\in Y$ is non-zero. By the Hahn-Banach theorem we can find a functional $f\in Y^*$ so that $f(y)\neq0$. But now $f\circ T$ is (linear, of course) and continuous by assumption, so $|f\circ T(x_n)|\leq \|f\circ T\|\cdot\|x_n\|$. Letting $n\to\infty$ we conclude that $f\circ T(x_n)\to0$. But since $f$ itself is continuous and $T(x_n)\to y$, we have that $f\circ T(x_n)=f(T(x_n))\to f(y)$, so $f(y)=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: How does the boundedness of $T$ guarantee continuity?

Comment: @user640718 A linear operator $T:X\to Y$ between normed spaces is continuous if and only if there exists a constant $C>0$ so that $\|T(x)\|\leq C\|x\|$ (this is what it means for $T$ to be bounded). This can be found on any introductory book on functional analysis. For a quick proof of what you are asking: if $T$ is bounded and $x_n\to x$, then $\|T(x_n)-T(x)\|=\|T(x_n-x)\|\leq C\|x_n-x\|\to0$, so $Tx_n\to Tx$ so $T$ is continuous.